# Most efficient way to determine circle coordinates?

Tags: c, geometry

I am making a function for drawing a circle in 2d space.
For this, I have identified 2 approaches:

- go through all the possible pixels and run them through a formula that will return a value that shows whether the pixel coordinates are inside the circle, outside (bonus: or intersecting it)
- get all the circle pixels (basically draw the circle)

I tried to look at some math sources, but I have met with some problems:

- in the second approach, the resolution at which I am incrementing the angle matters, so if it is too little, or radius is too small, there will be unnecessary duplication. On the other hand, if the angle gets incremented by more, or radius is too large, there will be gaps.

The formula I was using is:

```
struct vec2{int x; int y;};

void get_circle(int x, int y, int r, int angle, struct vec2 *coordinates) {
    coordiantes->x = x + r * cos(angle);
    coordinates->y = y + r * sin(angle);
}
```

This is obviously a bit much to run a lot of times.

I also want to make some kind of primitive anti-aliasing, so if I can get a value where a pixel only intersects the circle line by a half, it would be drawn as a half-pixel.

My final goal is to draw a nice circle with a line that can be thick. The thickness can be achieved with the area approach where I fill all pixels in a circle area, and then I remove pixels in the inner circle. Or it can be several iterations of the circle. I didn't write the array part of the computation, but yes, I would like each pixel identified. If we take a pixel as a rectangle, then I would like no pixel to be drawn if the theoretical circle goes through <33% of the surface, half-pixel 33-66, and full if >66%.

Please advise. I need some approach that will be computationally efficient.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: You have not defined what it means to draw a circle. First, does it mean to identify each pixel to be “drawn,” like iterating through those pixels on at a time or producing a list of them? Or would it mean identifying, for each pixel in a given area (such as a containing rectangle) whether the pixel is inside the circle or not? Or something else? Second, what specifically do you want to draw? If we consider each pixel as covering a tiny square in the plane, and the pixels completely tile and fill an area, do you want to “draw” each pixel that contains even a single point of the circle?…

Comment: … Or do you want some algorithm that draws a visually nice curved line, perhaps skipping pixels the circle just barely goes through because including them would make the drawing look clunky? Or something else? In other words, what are “the circle pixels”?

Comment: @sneaker,  Post definition of `struct vec2`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the condition was - whatever is more performant. My final goal is to draw a nice circle with a line that can be thick. The thickness can be achieved with the area approach where I fill all pixels in a circle area, and then I remove pixels in the innder circle. Or it can be several iterations of the circle. I didn't write the array part of the computation, but yes, I would like each pixel identified. If we take a pixel as a rectangle, then I would like no pixel to be drawn if the theoretical circle goes through <33% of the surface, half-pixel 33-66, and full if >66%.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica struct vec2{int x; int y;};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, "most efficient" depends on quite a few things. For most modern OpenGL systems you can usually get away with just computing points around the circumference using sine and cosine (and an appropriate aspect scale) with the native floating-point type, then plotting the points using any decent polyline algorithm.

Once you have things working, ***profile***.

If profiling shows your algorithm to be holding things up (and compared to other normal and common computations, it shouldn't be), only then should you spend time and effort on trickier (read: more complicated) stuff, like the Midpoint Circle Algorithm to generate points to send to your polyline.

Also, don't forget to memoize into a sprite or texture or pixmap or whatever is appropriate for your hardware/software IFF profiling shows a worthwhile improvement.